# Writing a dataframe to a csv file that has a lot of punctuation - but getting it broken into multiple rows

Tags: html, r, csv, export-to-csv, quotes

I have this data frame with one URL:

```
df <- data.frame("url" = "http://www.nycourts.gov/reporter/3dseries/2011/2011_00286.htm", "text" = "")
```

I am trying to get the entire text of the webpage (including HTML tags) and save it to a CSV file.

I've tried:

```
df$text[1] <- getURL(url=df$url[1])
```

and

```
df$text[1] <- paste(readLines(df$url[1]), collapse="")
```

These work fine, the problem is when I try to save it to a CSV. I've used:

```
write.csv(df, "file.csv")
write_csv(df, "file.csv")
write_delim(df1, "file.csv", delim = ",")
```

But the csv that result doesn't contain all of the text in the "text" column in one row. Instead, depending on the write function I use, it saves it in different rows / columns.

I've tried playing with write_delim's quote and escape parameters but nothing worked. I don't understand what's going wrong with the text in this url.

Comment: Why are you saying that the output "file.csv" file has "different rows / columns"? Are you using Excel to open this text file?  Works fine for me when I look at this file in notepad.

Comment: Yes, I have been using Excel. But this also happened when I had not opened the csv file, and later read it with read.csv, resulting in a new dataframe with a lot more rows.

Comment: Your problem lies not in R but in Excel, which has a limit to the number of characters that can exist in any cell (32,767). The text in your url contains more than this.